Insert Action in BuddyPress account settings page
I run Memberpress with a BuddyPress integration. On the Buddypress Account page I want to insert this snippet of code on the Membership -> Info page right above the Buddypress form fields: <?php echo FrmFormsController::get_form_shortcode( array( 'id' => 3 ) ); ?>

Anyone here who has experience with this that could help me out? Thank you.
